# Sorting complex json

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sorting

Friends, I have the following object in javascript:

```
{
    id:     {0: 3,      1: 2,       2: 1}
    amount: {0: 1000,   1: 5000,    2: 300},
    date:   {0: "aaa",  1: "bbb",   2: "ccc"}
}
```

how do I sort it descending by "amount" key? The "id" and "date" objects must be rearranged according to the sorted amount

The expected result is:

```
{
    id:     {0: 2,      1: 3,       2: 1}
    amount: {0: 5000,   1: 1000,    2: 300},
    date:   {0: "bbb",  1: "aaa",   2: "ccc"}
}
```

Comment: Please, post a snipet with your attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort the keys of `amount` by `amount` and use the order of these sorted keys to recreate the objects in the new order:

```
const x = {
    id:     {0: 3,      1: 2,       2: 1}, 
    amount: {0: 1000,   1: 5000,    2: 300},
    date:   {0: "aaa",  1: "bbb",   2: "ccc"}, 
};

const newX = Object.keys(x.amount)
  .sort((a, b) => x.amount[b] - x.amount[a])
  .reduce((a, c, i) => ({
    id: { ...a.id, [i]: x.id[c] },
    amount: { ...a.amount, [i]: x.amount[c] },
    date: { ...a.date, [i]: x.date[c] },
 }), { id: {}, amount: {}, date: {} }) ;

console.log(newX);
```

Comment: Thank you! it worked perfectly. It's been days trying to sort this object - which I agree it is ugly to work with, but it is what I am getting from the frontend. Very clean solution.

Comment: @CarlosAlzate Clean? Maybe. Concise? Sure. Readable/maintainable? Not really.

Answer (score 0):

I would first recommend changing your data layout. It is not in a sort friendly format. I would recommend the following instead:

```js
[
    {id: 2, amount: 5000, date: "bbb"},
    {id: 3, amount: 1000, date: "aaa"},
    {id: 1, amount: 300, date: "ccc"},
]
```

Once that is done, you can sort the array on a subkey using a sortBy method like: https://caolan.github.io/async/v3/sortBy.js.html

Ex:

```js
sortBy(obj2, (row) => row.amount, (result) => {
    console.log(result);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, data in this format is really ugly to work with. My suggestion would be if there's any way to change the structure, it would be highly preferable. However, if that's not the case, you can manipulate the data to a workable format, sort it, and then manipulate it back to the original format, like so:

```js
let data = {
    id:     {0: 3,      1: 2,       2: 1},
    amount: {0: 1000,   1: 5000,    2: 300},
    date:   {0: "aaa",  1: "bbb",   2: "ccc"}
}

// group data by index i.e. id[0], amount[0], and date[0] should be grouped together
let grouped = Object.entries(data.id).reduce((res, curr) => {
  let [key, value] = curr;
  res.push([data.id[key], data.amount[key], data.date[key]]);
  return res;
}, []);


// sort by index 1 (amount) descending
let sorted = grouped.sort((a,b) => {
  return b[1] - a[1];
});

// take sorted data and put back into original structure
let final = sorted.reduce((res, curr, index) => {
  let [id, amount, date] = curr;
  res.id[index] = id;
  res.amount[index] = amount;
  res.date[index] = date;
  return res;
}, {id: {}, amount: {}, date: {}});

console.log(final);
```